# How to keep the MDSpinner spinning while fetching data in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm developing a Kivy app that requires to fetch some data from an API. I want to show a MDSpinner spinning while the data is being fetched. The problem is, when the data begins to be fetched, the spinner stops spinning. It's kind of like the app is frozen. What is the correct way to use a MDSpinner? I will appreciate some basic example.

Comment: Fetch your data using a `Thread`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I actually need an example for that.

Comment: Search for "python threading example".

Comment: @JohnAnderson I searched for it and perfectly worked. Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JohnAnderson mentioned in the comments, the solution for kivy is to use threading. Just create the table, fetch the data in another thread and set the row_data attribute to the fetched data.